# Finding Total rows for query which uses Limit

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I have a function which return me X rows, where X is user selected parameter. I know I can use SQLCALCFOUND_ROWS in query, but I have to use select foundrows(); immediate after. If use select foundrows() after the main query inside my cfquery tag, only the values of total rows are returned. If I use it in another cfquery, it is possible that there is another query in mysql thread and my results are not available. What would be the better way to handle this.

Comment: If the objective is pagination, there are lots of examples of how to do it on the web.  Query caching comes to mind as one method.

Comment: You would need to check the performance, but you can do this in 2 `cfqueries`. 1. Run the query to get the data that you need. 2. Run the SAME query, but use `SQLCALCFOUND_ROWS` and `select foundrows()`. Also, you have the question tagged as 'MySQL', and mention some MySQL commands, yet you mention `mssql`. What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @Dan, I have already done the pagination (implemented db side) and it works very well. I want total number of records for particular search criteria to be returned along with my normal results, that is where I am finding difficulty.

Comment: @Scott, performance is key factor, currently doing it with 2 queries and it is taking a hit. Want to do it with single call hence the question :)

Comment: what if I use main query with SQLCALCFOUND_ROWS and then immediately after run another query for select foundrows(); and run both these queries in a cftransaction?

Comment: The only other option I can think of is to run a sub-query that gets the count and puts it in a column in the query - but, you are still technically running 2 queries.

Comment: The only way to know is to try it. It certainly sounds reasonable.

Comment: In fact I have tried it and it works well. But as you know, things always works alright on dev machines :) One question, when running those 2 cfqueries inside cftransaction, they will always run consecutively and Db won't run anything else from other connection thread?

Comment: @CFML_Developer - It is about the *connection*, not the database itself.  Of course the db will still execute sql from other threads. However, `foundrows()` is linked to the connection and ["only one request can use a connection at any time"](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/database-connections-handled-coldfusion.html). Using cftransaction ensures the request keeps the same connection, ie blocking other threads from using the connection until the enclosed queries are done and the connection is returned to the pool (assuming connection pooling is enabled).

Comment: Then that's it. Thanks for clearing the doubt. So, can I assume that this is the best approach in available circumstances: Running 2 cfqueries within cftransaction, first one primary query with SQLCALCFOUND_ROWS and second CFquery just do the select foundrows(); which I guess will be faster than executing complex primary query twice?

Comment: Well "best" is relative ;-) My guess is that approach would offer *some* improvement over running the same query twice, but logically those functions still do something similar internally. So again, the only way to determine which is best, is to test it, checking both performance *and* `explain plan` results and pick the one which is best for your application.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I implemented it by wrapping my queries in a `cftransaction`. Please NOTE: I have to resort to this method only when my primary query is huge and/or running that as subquery to get total record count is not an option. MySql states that `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` should run immediately after the query with `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`. If I run it in same `cfquery` tag, I cannot access data from my primary query. If I run another cfquery there is risk that query connection will be returned to pool. @Leigh mentioned that running both queries within a `cftransaction` ensures that the connection is retained.
Not the best solution, but much better than running a huge query twice.

```
<cftransaction>    
    <cfquery name="qry1" datasource="dsn">
         select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS col1,col2 from someTable
         some complex joins
         where a=b
    </cfquery>
    <cfquery name="qry2" datasource="dsn">
         select FOUND_ROWS() as TotalRows;
    </cfquery>
</cftransaction>
```

Comment: *RE: I cannot access data from my primary query* The reason for this is that `CFQuery` only returns returns a single resultset. If you need to return multiple resultsets, say 1) a total count and 2) detailed results, you should look into using `cfstoredproc` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This answer depends very much on the complexity and time cost of your query.  But in a simple example, you can just build a count into the initial query as a subselect.  If you have a table of countries for example, you can do the following to get the top 10 and also the total number

```
select top 10 
  country_name
  ,(select COUNT(*) from country) as total
from 
  country
```

Comment: Thanks :) as you mentioned it will work in SIMPLE example but not in complex query with lot of joins exactly the position I am in :)

Comment: Are you sure you have the appropriate indexes? You might speed your query up an order of magnitude by stopping MySQL from doing full table scans.

Comment: Another alternative, again depending on how often your underlying data is changing, is to use ColdFusion's built in SOLR support.  You can load all of your data into SOLR and index incrementally at fairly low cost.  This would allow you run multiple searches extremely cheaply.  We did this with complex joins on tens of millions of records and got *several* orders of magnitude improvements.  You can extend CF's native support and augment the SOLR custom fields to be more meaningful without much pain as well.

Answer (score -1):

You could just do a query of the query object that's returned. Feed the name of the query as the datasource and you can run SQL on it. I believe you should be able to do a select count(*)  and count the rows that are returned from the first query.

Comment: so if you are implying that I fetch all records say 2000 and then QoQ to get top X (say 50) from them? Query is complex, and takes lot of time. In fact this was the method used earlier, but if user wants to see only 10 records per page, there is no point fetching all 2000. So I did the pagination on mySql server side with Limit. But not finding any way to fetch Total record count.

Comment: *could just do a query of the query object that's returned* You could, but it is really not a good idea. What happens when the query returns 20K or 100K records? Returning thousands of records that are never used, defeats the purpose of pagination (not scalable).

Comment: Well you would of course use limit and offset but I thought this was about finding how many rows were returned without fearing something in that thread skewing the results. If I limit to 100 and pull back 88 then the query of query method works, but I wouldn't pull back 10k rows to scrape 50 and paginate it.

Comment: The OP was not extremely clear, but my take on it is this is a typical pagination task, ie Apply a query filter and A) estimate the total number of records available, then B) return `X` records from those results. So performing the count in the db is obviously more efficient.